# How to use Pyinstaller in Jupyter to create executable Python files?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to generate an executable file from a python code I have been working on. Since I am new to programming in python all I do is within my Jupyter notebooks.

So far I have the code done and it does what I want. I have created my Python script (.py) with the File-> download as-> Python (.py).

Now that I have the Python script I have run `pip install pyinstaller` and apparently everything is ok, this is the returned message:

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Downloading pyinstaller-5.11.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.3/1.3 MB 27.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pefile>=2022.5.30
  Downloading pefile-2023.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 71.8/71.8 kB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\josed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4
  Downloading pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 263.6/263.6 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting altgraph
  Downloading altgraph-0.17.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=42.0.0 in c:\users\josed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (63.4.1)
Installing collected packages: altgraph, pyinstaller-hooks-contrib, pefile, pyinstaller
Successfully installed altgraph-0.17.3 pefile-2023.2.7 pyinstaller-5.11.0 pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2023.3
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

But after this I try to run `pyinstaller program1.py` and I come up with:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Can I get some insight on what am I doing wrong and how to do it correctly?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the correct approach. When I perform the following steps, it seems to work:

1. In Jupyter Notebook, go to File > Download As > Python (.py) and save your notebook as a .py file.
2. In Anaconda Prompt, install Pyinstaller by running `pip install pyinstaller`.
3. In Anaconda Prompt, navigate to the folder where your .py file is located and run `pyinstaller --onefile yourfile.py`. This will create a single file .exe program in the dist folder.

Are you by any chance running pyinstaller directly in your Jupyter notebook file?

Another approach might be to convert the notebook into a script directly:
`jupyter nbconvert --to script program1.ipynb`.

Then, running `python program1.py` should produce your desired results.

Comment: Many thanks for the help StudentCS! With this directions I was totally able to get my executable file! I was indeed running pyinstaller in the notebook file instead of the suggested Anaconda powershell prompt, looks like this is where I was going wrong. If it is not much asking, can you tell me why I cannot use the pyinstaller from Jupyter? I want to understand why this is incorrect so I can keep learning. Many thanks!

Comment: If this was the correct answer, please accept my answer as a correct answer :) The reason why you cannot use pyinstaller in Jupyter Notebook is that Jupyter Notebook is not a command prompt. Pyinstaller is a command-line tool that requires you to run it from a command prompt. You can use the Anaconda Powershell prompt or any other command prompt to run Pyinstaller.

Comment: Yes it was! I marked the green checkmark on the side, believe that marks it at correct answer ( sorry didnt know how the whole process works, this was my first post, will do from now on :) ). Many thanks for all the help and insight!